# Remove all values => 0 from array and reverse it

Tags: php, arrays

I am a PHP beginner and have the following problem that I completely get stuck. I have an array in this format

```
Array (
  [date] => 0
  [author] => 1
  [categories] => 1
  [tags] => 0
  [comments] => 0
  [readmore] => 0
)
```

Now I need to remove all items that are `[value] => 0` from that array and get it in this format

```
Array (
  [0] => author
  [1] => categories
)
```

Any input in this is much appreciated.

Comment: `$array_without_zero = array_unique($array)`

Comment: Review :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/43320034/2667307

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and then [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php):

```
$array = array ( 'date' => 0, 'author' => 1, 'categories' => 1, 'tags' => 0, 'comments' => 0, 'readmore' => 0 );
$array = array_filter($array);
print_r(array_keys($array));
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => author
    [1] => categories
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `array_search()` out there. Assuming the only possible values are `0` and `1`, you can just serach the whole array for this value:

```
$array = [
  'date' => 0,
  'author' => 1,
  'categories' => 1,
  'tags' => 0,
  'comments' => 0,
  'readmore' => 0
];
$new_array = array_flip(array_search(1, $array));
```

So `print_r($new_array)` will give you your desired result.

Comment: your code have syntax error, also array srarch will return key if thord parameter is not used. So in case array_flip will give error for parameter required as array

Comment: should be fixed now, forgot the commas.

Comment: @ShashankShah i see my error, nice solution btw. :)

Comment: :) Thank you @TobiasF.

Comment: @Tobias F. he did not said that i want to keep the element which has 1, is said he has to unset the array index where value is 0

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach($array as $item){
 if($item == "0"){
  unset($item);
 }
}
```

Or some modification with using unset function.

Answer (score 0):

This is also do the job...

```
$dataSource = array('data' => 0,
        'author' => 1,
        'categories' => 1,
        'tags' => 0,
        'comments' => 0,
        'readmore' => 0,
    );

$updatedDataList = array();
foreach ($dataSource as $key => $value) {
    if($value !== 0) {
        $updatedDataList[] = $key;
    }
}

print_r($updatedDataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
$yourArray = Array ("date" => 0,"author" => 1, "categories" => 1,"tags" => 0, "comments" => 0,"readmore" => 0 );
$removeZeroFromArray = array(0);
$desiredResult = array_diff($yourArray, $removeZeroFromArray);                          
echo"<pre>";
print_r(array_keys($desiredResult));
echo"</pre>";
```

Your **output** will be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => author
    [1] => categories
)
```

Alternate way should be

```
$desiredResult = array_filter($yourArray, function($a) { return ($a !== 0); });
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

@savethegold you can save your gold like below :D

```
<?php
    $Array1 =   array("date" => 0, "author" => 1, "categories" => 1, "tags" => 0, "comments" => 0, "readmore" => 0 );
    foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value) {
        if($value == 0){
            unset($Array1[$key]);
        }
    }
    $finalArr = array_keys($Array1);
    print_r($finalArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array ( 'date' => 0, 'author' => 1, 'categories' => 1, 'tags' => 0, 'comments' => 0, 'readmore' => 0 );
$resutl = [];
foreach($array as $k => $v)
{
  if($v != 0)
    $result[] = $k;
}
print_r($result);
```